# voice recognition algorithm to convert number

Tags: microcontroller, voice, arduino-ide

I was making voice commanded calculator..in that I prestored some of the voicedata of
(1 to 9),(10 ,20 --90),(hundred ,thousand, lakh).
if I want to calculate 1234+45678
 I need to say ""one thousand two hundred thirty four plus forty five thousand six hundred seventy eight"
my voice recognition system recognize it as {1,1000,2,100,40,4,}+{40,5,1000,6,100,70,8}
but I don't know how to write the program to calculate the above problem. I hope you understood my problem and found one better solution for that..
I have planned one solution but it having some loop holes
in that first bracket it

> rule 1: multiply the consecutive numbers and add the result,
>   rule 2: if the first number in the consecutive groups is found to be
>   10,20,30,40...90.it will add to the next number in that consecutive
>   instead of multiplying
>   rule 3: it will continue until it found any
>   symbols like (+,-*,/) ,like this (1*1000)+(2*100)+(30+4)=1234
>   similarly second bracket and add the result

I was not satisfied with the above procedure so,please try to find the better solution. I will be very thankful to you.

If it is not clear with my problem leave it in the comments I will try to explain my level best.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers 11-13 sound different but I'll assume you handle that within your "tens" code.

Anyway, the first pass through each array should produce alternating pairs of "number" and "multiplier"
such that

```
[40, 5, 1000, 6, 100, 70, 8]
```

becomes

```
[45, 1000, 6, 100, 78]
```

Then you can do your multiply and add.  But modify the rule slightly so that it tests if the next number is evenly divisible by 10. Like this:

```
int i = 0;
int temp_result = 0;
while(i <= size_of_array){
    if(i == size_of_array - 1){
        temp_result = temp_result + array[i];
    }
    else{
        if(array[i+1] % 10){
            temp_result = temp_result + array[i]*array[i+1];
        }else{
            temp_result = temp_result + array[i];
        }
    }
    i = i + 2;
}
```